# Fill a double pointer matrix from CSV file

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want to fill a double pointer 2D array with the values from a CSV. I don't want to read the csv file to get the size of the array before filling it and I want to do it with pointers and not std::vector. My current code is this

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> readFile(const std::string &filename, int **matrix) {
  std::fstream file{filename, std::ios::in};
  if (file.is_open()) {
    std::string line{};
    int col{0};
    int row{0};
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
      // Check how many cols there are
      int len = std::count(begin(line), end(line), ',') + 1;
      // Allocate a vector with size the cols found before
      int *tmp = reinterpret_cast<int *>(calloc(len, sizeof(int)));
      col = 0;
      // Fill the temp vector with the read numbers
      while (line.size() > 0) {
        int num{-1};
        // This is just to parse a number, nothing special here
        if (line.find(",") != std::string::npos) {
          num = std::stoi(line.substr(0, line.find(",")));
          line.erase(0, line.find(",") + 1); // +1 to also delete delimiter
        } else {
          num = std::stoi(line);
          line = ""; // Set line empty to go out of the while
        }
        tmp[col] = num;
        col++;
      }
      // Assign the temporal vector to a row of the matrix
      matrix[row] = tmp;
      row++;
    }
    return {row, col};
  }
  std::cout << "Failed to open file at " << filename << std::endl;
  return {-1, -1};
}

int main() {
  int **matrix;
  auto shape = readFile("file.csv", matrix);
  for (size_t row = 0; row < shape.first; row++) {
    for (size_t col = 0; col < shape.second; col++) {
      std::cout << matrix[row][col] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  // Free the pointers
  for (size_t row = 0; row < shape.first; row++) {
    free(matrix[row]);
  }
}
```

My current result is:

```
0 0 -751362032 21853 1 
2 3 4 2 3 
2 1 3 4 5 
3 2 1 4 3 
2 2 2 2 2 
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It seems that the fist tmp vector is being freed before the print (the rest of the values are right). Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: _"and I want to do it with pointers and not `std::vector1."_ whatever you want,  but could you please elaborate any other reasons aside homework or studying why you don't want it, and how the standard implementation doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: "*what I'm missing?*" High level abstractions, RAII and some insights on memory management

Comment: yes, pure educational, of course std::vector is better suited for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `matrix` to your `readFile` function uninitialized, and then go on and access it with `matrix[i]=tmp`. That can cause all kinds of issues since you're working with memory that doesn't belong to you.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to initialize the double pointer. Right now I'm iterating over the file lines to get the number of rows and allocate the memory of matrix double ptr. I guess there's no way of doing this without going through the whole file.